# Поймать событие по клику на элемент JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

по работе приходится иметь дело с одним online сервисом ( на bootstrap), функционал у них немного хромает и хотелось бы его немного допилить. 
Т.к сделать изменения в первоначальном коде я не могу, решил использовать расширение для chrome - TamperMonkey, оно позволяет интегрировать свой JS на любой сайт. 
Сайт устроен так, что при клике на опр. div загружается меню(модальное окно). Так вот мне бы при появлении этого меню чуть поправить некоторые элементы в нем при помощи JS. 
В JS я слаб.

Пробовал ждать появления меню вот так с ajax:

```html
if ($("div").hasClass('класс нашего меню')) {
   alert(1); //поймали загрузку меню.
}
```

Код не отрабатывает через tampermonkey*( директиву // @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js добавил)* , если добавляю код через инспектор(F12) то код работает, правда один раз. Если закрыть меню и открыть заново - alert уже не появляется. 
Сам сайт на bootstrap.
С Уважением, Waik.

Comment: после поиска проверяйте видимый ли элемент. или назначьте меню событие onclick тогда будет не один раз срабатывать.

Comment: Спасибо. А зачем проверять видимость, он либо есть в DOM( а значит активен) либо его нет.

Comment: Да и как мне повесить click на него, если я его поймать не могу?

Comment: Ну сначала по классу поймать же получается, а потом назначайте онклик. Почему в плагине не работает не знаю, я работал с аналогичным плагином под файрфокс, все ок было, но jquery не подключал.